# Is "solve this n-body system for me" on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

Are worldbuilding-style questions which boil down to "is this *n*-body system I've invented stable" on-topic for this site?

As examples I am talking about things like

- [Is this a potential planetary setup for the Alpha Centauri System?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35643/24157)
- [Is a Procyon - brown dwarf - Jupiter - superearth - Mars - Pluto system theoretically possible?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36128/24157)

Since these questions are in general unanswerable in a definitive fashion, should they be allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that questions which are "unanswerable in a definitive fashion" are *ever* good SE questions, no. I think that a question like that can be closed using existing reasons pretty quickly, but it could also be edited, or closed as duplicate to a canonical answer.

*These* questions linked above are in fact questions about building specific solar systems of their OP's invention, not [thought experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment) intended to understand astronomical principles, so they're not really about Astronomy and they are really World Building questions.

You could simply ask

> Should we start accepting World Building questions?

and to that I'd say we probably shouldn't, because where does it end?

Instead, maybe we can collect a list of answered questions that address stability and offer it as a resource for users wanting to ask about building worlds.

Comment: Good answer! I agree.